# Theme attributes for specific component types

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Can I define attributes in a theme that will apply only on specific components, such as an EditText, like what can be done in CSS with, e.g, `.table`? I know I can define a style and set it on all the components, but I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme, add `<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/<your substyle name>`:

```
<style name="My.Mega.Theme" >
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/My.Mega.Theme.EditText</item>
</style>

<style name="My.Mega.Theme.EditText" parent="My.Mega.Theme">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Replace `editTextStyle` with `buttonStyle` for buttons, and so on.

You can even have analogs of css classes for controls of the same class, like:

(styles file):

```
<attr name="note" format="reference" />

<style name="My.Mega.Theme" >
    <item name="note">@style/My.Mega.Theme.SmallText</item>
</style>
```

(layout file):

```
<TextView style="?note"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure every control has a corresponding item for its style. To me it actually seems these items represent styles for general UI components that can be part of many composite views. For example, buttonStyle sets the style for Button views, but it may also affect the buttons in a NumberPicker. Then again, I haven't checked it, so I might be wrong here. Any other comments and answers are welcome.